# Why do some git commands fail when run via crontab?

Tags: git, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job (macOS) that periodically accesses a remote git repository that I own. However, I'm running into some trouble accessing my git credentials when running commands using crontab.

When I run the equivalent of `git config --global -l` via crontab, I'm able to access my git configurations:

```
user.name=myUsername
user.email=myEmail@gmail.com
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=osxkeychain`
```

However, when I try and pull from the remote via crontab, the following error is thrown:

```
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

Additionally, when I run `/usr/bin/security find-internet-password -gs github.com` via crontab, I get the error:

```
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Even though this works from the shell.

I'm confused as to why I'm able to read from my git config but git isn't able to read from the keychain. Is there a way to manually pass keychain parameters to git? Do I have to set specific permissions for my keychain?

I'm aware of similar posts but don't feel that they answered these questions.

Comment: This could be due to `cron` not running as you. In most case, `cron` runs as an independent user with much fewer privileges for safety reasons.

Comment: Typically the issue is multiple versions of Git installed (you get the wrong one) and/or other similar path issues. There are also occasional issues with home directories or other environment variable settings. (And, on MacOS, keychain access is somewhat magic but I'm not sure of any of the details.)

Comment: @torek I don't think the issue is git path related as running git config via crontab returns the correct values. Can I manually give `cron` increased permissions?

Comment: Different versions of `git` share the config file format. Use `git --version` and `git --exec-path` to show which version of Git you're running and which `git-core` directory that version searches (you can potentially have issues if you `brew install` even the *same* Git that the system XCode installed, if the two versions use different exec paths). As for OSX keychain stuff, I know only that it exists, not how to fuss with it.

Comment: Are you using ssh to access your repo? If not, you might want to try it. You can then  use key access. It makes authentication platform agnostic.